# Unfolding a definition without reduction

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The [Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.unfold) states that the `unfold qualid` tactic unfolds each occurrence of `qualid` in the goal and replaces it with its beta-iota-normal form.

Is there a simple way to unfold a definition without triggering beta/iota reduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try e.g. the [`cbv` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html?highlight=cbv#coq:tacn.cbv) like so:

```
Definition foo := (fun (x : nat) => x) 42.
Definition bar := (fun (x : nat) => x) 42.

Goal foo = bar.
  cbv delta [foo].
```

This results in the following proof state:

```
(fun x : nat => x) 42 = bar
```